# CMake can't find glog

Tags: cmake

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.7 FATAL_ERROR)

INCLUDE(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

FIND_LIBRARY(GLOG_LIBRARY glog)
FIND_PATH(GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR "glog/logging.h")

SET(GLOG_LIBRARIES ${GLOG_LIBRARY})

FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(
  Glog
  REQUIRED_ARGS GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR GLOG_LIBRARY)
```

This is the cmake file. I installed the `google glog 0.3.4` in the `/apps/glog`. Why when compiling this file, there is still the following error? I checked, `glog/logging.h` is under `0.3.4/include/glog/`.

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindGlog.cmake:77 (MESSAGE):
  Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set
  GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/FindGlog.cmake:103 (GLOG_REPORT_NOT_FOUND)
  CMakeLists.txt:27 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: Command [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_path.html) searches requested file (`glog/logging.h`) under some system directories. I guess, directory `/apps/glog/0.3.4/` is not one of the system ones, so it is not searched by default. You may hint CMake about this directory by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable when call `cmake`: `cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/apps/glog/0.3.4 ...`.

Comment: Yes..  I was using a system that every time I want to use a library, I must load it from "apps". And all the libraries are managed by the administrator. I don't quite understand the mechanism. But I think this is the main issue. I will try your method.

Answer (score 2):

Glog now (at most four years after this question was asked) has CMake support! They have very good documentation here: https://github.com/google/glog#cmake

But this is the gist of what you should do:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0.2)
project(myproj VERSION 1.0)

find_package(glog 0.6.0 REQUIRED)

add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE glog::glog)
```

Just like any other well-behaved, CMake-aware library!

Answer (score 1):

As of November 18, 2017, official glog does not support CMake.

GitHub user `sergiud` added CMake support in a fork.
Please see the discussion in
https://github.com/google/glog/issues/4.